# How to manipulate google chrome's PRINT option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, printing

I want to disable COPIES option of google chrome using `javascript` or `jQuery`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('body,html').click( function(e){ e.preventDefault(); return false;});
```

Comment: any other way for this?

Comment: Try to prevent mousedown, click and keydown(Ctr+C), so you can do this. This is my idea.